# What is iOS 9.3 system font name?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, fonts, ui-design

I would like to know the name of the default system font on the iPhone. It used to be "HelveticaNeue" I guess , but now?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

iOS 9 uses SanFranciscoUIDisplay and SanFranciscoText as their default font.

SanFranciscoUIDisplay is used for titles and larger font wheres SanFranciscoText is used for paragraph text and smaller font.

They are the System Font in Xcode or you can download them here (but you need a developer account):

[developer.apple.com/fonts/](http://developer.apple.com/fonts/)

You can use the default font like this:

Swift 2:

```
UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
```

Swift 3 and Swift 4:

```
UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
```

Comment: what string should i put in this code? UIFont(name: "String", size: 15.0). Thanks

Comment: Because it is the system font, you can just use UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)

Comment: Oh, I see. OMG :D Thanks

Comment: what is the equivalent of this font in HTML ?

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 & 4

```
UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
```